# Как правильно сделать админку модулем Yii?

Tags: php, yii

Всем привет, начал делать сайт на PHP фреймворке Yii, до этого делал несколько сайтов визиток на Yii, однако серьезных проектов не было (сайт над которым сейчас работаю - первый крутой проект на Yii). Вопрос такой - **Как правильно сделать админку модулем Yii?** Я создал с помощью Gii модуль admin и добавил запись о новом модуле в конфиг. Но что делать дальше не пойму? Кто может подсказать?

Comment: Использую Yii первой версии...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

есть много вариантов, один раз даже применял этот метод:
http://habrahabr.ru/post/117457/

Но сейчас делю просто главный контроллер mainController и от туда еще два контроллера унаследую frontController и backController всё это делается в mainModule в папке components/controllers/. Все модули должны унаследоваться от mainModule в том чиле и adminModule. Создать роли для посетителей. если гость или просто зарегистрированный юзер то будем работать с frontController а если роль администратор или модератор показываем меню админской панели а там все контроллеры должны унаследоваться от BackController. И создать правило, что BackController доступно только юзерам с роли admin && moderator.